# signed to unsigned conversions

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A riddle (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611724/a-riddle-in-c)

see this code

```
  #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])) 

  int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16}; 

  int main() 

  { 

      int d; 

      for(d=-1;d <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2;d++) 
          printf("%d\n",array[d+1]); 

      return 0;

  }
```

now this loop won't run.
sizeof() would return an unsigned value so TOTAL_ELEMENTS has an unsigned value.
now , coming to the for loop, please tell me if the unary operator '-' works on signed int 2 or an implicit conversion takes place into unsigned and then the '-' operator works.

Comment: I can't decide if I like this question since it points out a detail that people often overlook or hate it because the example code is clearly bad code.  I'm hoping that it was written only to show the problem and doesn't exist in "real life."

Comment: It's a pretty artificial problem - a better example is checking that a signed number is below a maximum and then passing it to malloc.

Answer (score 8):

In your example **d** is converted to an *unsigned int* in the comparison. But -1 cannot be represented as an *unsigned int* value, so it is is converted to UINT_ MAX. To avoid this behaviour you can convert the right side of the comparison to an signed *int* by prepending *(int)*.

See [Understand integer conversion rules](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) for details on integer conversion in C.

Comment: That's the premise of the question.  However, I think he's asking about arithmetic conversion rules.

Comment: I tried to point out why the code does not work and provided a link to a document that explains the promotion rules. Of course, to give a complete answer I should explained the rules and explained that 2 is converted to an unsigned it before it is substracted from TOTAL_ELEMENTS.

Answer (score 2):

There's no unary operator in d <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2.

The TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2 reduces to an expression with a binary operator of -. This expression then becomes unsigned because one of its operands is unsigned.

In the case of d <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2, d's type is also converted to unsigned int for the same reason.

The relevant portion of the standard is section 6.3.1.8#1 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) which says:

"Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
integer type."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `d` also has an unsigned type in that expression, because of promotion, which is why the loop fails.

However, the question is whether the C compiler "thinks":

`(unsigned) ((unsigned) 5 - (unsigned) 2)`

i.e. promoting 2 to unsigned, or:

`(unsigned) ((unsigned) 5 - (signed) 2)`

i.e. subtraction taking operands of both types. Of course, it doesn't matter, as it would be the same operation for both.  However, the whole point is that subtracting will return a value of one type, so theoretically it can only take arguments of that type.  So it's the first (unsigned int 2).

P.S. (-2) is unary, while (5 - 2) is binary.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the unsigned type of `sizeof()` to propagate to the expression `TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2` and then to both operands of `d <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2`. Inserting `(int)` juste before `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

look , that '-' operator being unary was a stupid thing.forget it.it was the binary '-' , i realise.

when 2 is converted to unsigned int it becomes unsigned 2 , so TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2 has a value equal to unsigned 5 , and then when d is being converted to an unsigned int it gets a large positive value and
so the loop fails.

is that happening here??

and yes, i didn't write this code,this is some c puzzle i found on the web.
thank ya all.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much what happens.