# C Program sizeof or macro, Something is wrong

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A riddle (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611724/a-riddle-in-c)

Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{
  int d;

  for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
      printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it is the signed/unsigned issue. But what's _really_ wrong here is why you'd write this bizarre code in the first place.

Comment: @paxdiablo, this was a puzzle in one of the papers I was looking at !!! Just trying to have perfection in understanding C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)
```

`d` is signed: it is an `int`.
But `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is unsigned: `sizeof` yields a `size_t` value and `size_t` is an unsigned type.

In the `<=` expression  `d` is converted to an unsigned number by the way of the usual arithmetic conversions and it becomes a huge number.

Answer (score 1):

When `d` is -1 and is compared with `TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2` (which is `size_t` type, ie an *unsigned* integer), `d` is promoted to a large number in an unsigned type. Then, `d` is greater than `TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2`, so the loop is never executed.

> > [c11](/questions/tagged/c11)
>
> **§ 6.5.8 Relational operators**
>   If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are
>   performed.
>
> **§ 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**
>   Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.