# automatic type conversions

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [signed to unsigned conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498805/signed-to-unsigned-conversions)
>   [A riddle (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611724/a-riddle-in-c)

I am trying to understand why this program is not working

```
 #include<stdio.h>

  #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
  int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

  int main()
  {
      int d;

      for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
          printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);

      return 0;
  }
```

I came across this program when I was going through automatic type conversions in C.But I don't understand how conversions happen between signed and unsigned data types.Please explain.
Thank you,
Harish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof()` is of type unsigned, wile `d` is signed.

you check if `d` is smaller then an unsigned integer. Thus, the signed `d` is converted to unsinged.

But the bits representaion of the signed `-1` when read as unsigned is greater then 2^31, and obviously greater then `TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2`, thus the condition is never met and you do not enter the for loop even once.

Look at this [code snap](http://ideone.com/ngulJ), it might clear up things for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { 
   unsigned int x = 50;
   int y = -1;
   printf("x < y is actually %u < %u which yields %u\n", y,x,y < x);
   return 0;
}
```

The above code prints:

> x < y is actually 4294967295 < 50 which yields 0